# Canot download Xamarin.GooglePlayServicesMaps using nuget

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget, maps

I have a problem. I try to download the google play services (Maps) but when I try to download, I have this error message:

Failed to restore the package. Reviving the package changes for "Prueba.Android".

I try to download for only a project and for all solution, but I still have the same error message. And also I try with:

Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps -Version 60.1142.0

And I have the next error message:

Install-Package : Detectado un conflicto de versiones para Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Para resolver este problema, haga referencia al paquete directamente desde el 
proyecto. 
 Prueba.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2) 
 Prueba.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2).
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps -Version 60.1142.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Error al restaurar el paquete. Revirtiendo los cambios del paquete para 'Prueba.Android'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps -Version 60.1142.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I take a screenshot to clarify.

[image]

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget is failing to install the package because you are trying to install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` which depends on the package `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` version >=26.0.2 and your current installed version is 25.4.0.2.

Updating `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` should resolve the issue.

You can use the following nuget package manager command to do this:

```
Update-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
```